# Typo in TikZ manual?

Tags: tikz-pgf

First of all, I resort to asking this here because it seemed a less bad idea then emailing Till Tantau directly.

Now, onto what I think is a typo. On the fourth paragraph of section 2.21 of the [fine manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), one reads that «there is an option called below, which does the same as anchor=north. Similarly, above right does the same as anchor=south east». Now, according to the explanation (given in the previous page of the manual), `anchor=south east` would mean the current position would be set "south east" of the text; or in other words, the text would be placed above **left**. Right (if you'll excuse the pun)? Or am I making some trivial mistake?

PS: While trying to put the link to the manual, I had to delete the `.pdf` part, then add it again, otherwise the link would not be recognised...

EDIT: Updated with info from Paul Gessler's comment.

Comment: I think you are correct, it should read: "Similarly, `above right` does the same as `anchor=south west`." Or: "Similarly, `above left` does the same as `anchor=south east`." But in any case, the manual you linked to is outdated. The same error appears in the [current `pgf` manual](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), in paragraph 4 of section 2.21.

Comment: Do not send mail directly to Till Tantau! Create a [ticket on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/).

Comment: Just submitted... and I got ticket #300! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug report.

Comment: When I originally wrote this question, it was for two reasons: I wanted to confirm that in fact it was a bug, and, if that was the case, where was the place to report it. To both I now have an answer. Furthermore, I had not thought this to be off-topic (otherwise I would not have posted it), but if more senior members of community deem it so, then I see no problem in closing the question.